# reactjs - Why have form value state updated through both parent props and component onChange?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I'm reading the Fullstack React book, and in their example on form validation, they create their own Field component (pg. 204 - 212), and then store the field value in both the Field state and parent state, which is confusing to me. Their Field component has a `value` prop as well as a state containing `value`. The parent component needs to know about each field value, so that it can do form validation as a whole, and so it also has a state containing `value`.

Within Field, they handle `value` changes by both setting the Field state when the input `value` changes, and by using `getDerivedStateFromProps` when the `value` prop changes:

```
//(within Field)
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
     return {value: nextProps.value}
}

onChange = evt => {
    const name = this.props.name;
    const value = evt.target.value;
    const error = this.props.validate ? this.props.validate(value) : false;

    this.setState({value, error});

    this.props.onChange({name, value, error});
};
```

They also sync the value state in the other direction to the parent by calling the parent's onInputChange function (passed as the onChange prop):

```
//(within parent component)
onInputChange = ({name, value, error}) => {
    const fields = Object.assign({}, this.state.fields);
    const fieldErrors = Object.assign({}, this.state.fieldErrors);

    fields[name] = value;
    fieldErrors[name] = error;

    this.setState({fields, fieldErrors});
};
```

The book doesn't really explain why they duplicate the state like this, except to say,

> "There are only two pieces of data that Field will need, the current
>   value and error. Like in previous sections where our form component
>   needed that data for its render() method, so too does our Field
>   component."

and also

> "One key difference is that our Field has a parent, and sometimes this
>   parent will want to update the value prop of our Field. To allow this,
>   we’ll need to create a new lifecycle method,
>   getDerivedStateFromProps() to accept the new value and update the
>   state."

I'm just a beginner, but in my mind, it would make more sense to ditch the `value` state altogether within Field, and have it just passed in as a prop. When the input changes, call the onChange method with Field, and call parent's onInputChange within that. Have onInputChange update the parent state about the field's value, and pass down the field value as a prop to the field. The way it's done now seems sort of redundant and more error prone. Any insight as to why they do it this way?

Comment: I totally agree with you. They should definetly lift the state up and keep a single source of truth.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, the only use case I can think of for duplicating state in a child component would be if you're trying to preserve the original state in some way.

Comment: The only reason I can possibly see if the example goes on where you have to build on top of this where it makes sense to decouple the states between children and parent.  Even so, it’s probably leading into a path of messy React architecture.  I’ll share my two cents, even to this day I have not read a good React tutorial or even taken a well written React assessment test. My skills of React all came the examples of the React and Redux site itself.

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks :)

But interesting guys, I guess I'll see if the way the do it makes sense later.

Comment: @josephnvu I like the book so far, so hopefully it makes sense later or it's just one confusing example :T

Comment: Keeping a local value can make sense if you only update the parent value in case it is valid. I have a validating input component that does exactly this. Maybe they are working towards something like that in your book?

Comment: I don't find this setup problematic. Forms are not your typical component; you often find this common pattern with form libraries, where the individual component maintains its own state, but then notifies the parent, which in turn must aggregate the state of the individuals and run a global validation.

Comment: @Oblosys I doubt it, I think they want to update the parent either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't read the book, but here I will explain why I would write such a code.

The main point in having the two states is to make the `Field` component more generic.

In that specific case, the parent happens to also save the value in his state, and the `Field` component becomes a controlled component by updating his state from the received `props` on `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

However there is still the possibility to use the `Field` component as an uncontrolled component, then the `Field`'s state would be the only source of truth.

In both cases there's only a single source of truth, which maintains React's way of doing things, however the `Field` component can be used in both a controlled and uncontrolled form.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes a lot of sense. They were talking before about converting their input forms from uncontrolled (using ref) to controlled components, and about how they don't really recommend uncontrolled. But I guess they did it this way here so it could still work uncontrolled.